# SystemVerilog Assertion consecutive repetition for overlapping sequences

Tags: system-verilog

I have a specification as follows :

"Check that 'valido' is not asserted when 'validi=1' for only two, one or zero consecutive clk cycles."

the following assertion FAILS (n-3 times) on a sequence of 111..1 :

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) disable iff (rst) validi[*0:2] |=> !valido);
```

I guess the problem is in my property, as it does not cover the case of overlapping sequences (?). Is there a way to write a property which would behave right?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion checks if `valido` is LOW when `validi` is HIGH for three consecutive clock cycles, so it is wrong. It will not work even if you change the trigger condition to `validi[*0:1]` due to overlapping sequences as you guessed.

I don't have a fix in that coding style, but a solution can be built using `$past` similar to the one on Verification Academy[*](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/sva-using-past).

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) disable iff (rst) 
    ($past(!validi, 0) || 
     $past(!validi, 1) || 
     $past(!validi, 2)) |=> !valido);
```

Now the assertion expects `valido` to be LOW if `validi` is LOW at least one of the last three clock cycles.